# How to shuffle a function consistently from a seed number

Tags: list, algorithm, shuffle, memory-efficient

I need a algorithm that sorts a list in a consistent way when given a input seed number and a list of unique items to shuffle.
Here are the properties it must satisfy:
Let's call the algorithm  function(list, seed_value)

- No randomness which means function([1, 2, 3, 4], n) is the same as function([1, 2, 3, 4], n) the next time it is called
- Every seed number that is more than 0 and less than or equal to the number of permutations of the list possible must give a unique shuffled list from the others.
- It is an algorithm, not a lookup table
- Efficient, timewise and spacewise
- As few loops as possible
- Easy to understand if possible

It's... a bit hard for me to comprehend so I am asking you people to help.
(btw even if it is not really random it doesn't matter for me)

Comment: In order to satisfy the second requirement, you may need to generate the N-th permutation, using some function of the seed as N (seeding a PRNG cannot make this guarantee). You don't need tables for that.

Comment: Technically n-th permutation (a known algorithm) does satisfy all of the above. Except it's not going to be shuffled much. Add a Fisher-Yates shuffle with a fixed-seed PRNG on top?

Comment: @teapot418 what do you mean by *"it's not going to be shuffled much"*? If a list has `N` possible permuations, and every seed from `1` to `N` returns one of these `N` permutations, what more do you want to shuffle?

Comment: @derpirscher If `shuffle([1,2,3,4],1) == [1,2,3,4]` and `shuffle([1,2,3,4],2) == [1,2,4,3]` always, I would consider the function a tad misnamed (too visibly deterministic?). But I guess it is up to OP, if that's usable for their purpose.

Comment: @teapot418 What difference does it make, whether the result of `shuffle([1,2,3,4],1) == [1,2,3,4]` or the result of `shuffle([1,2,3,4],5) == [1,2,3,4]`? If you read the requirements, especially number 2, it follows, that each permuation of the list has to occur as result of one seed from `1` .. `N`. And the first requirement explicitly states *no randomness*, ie for a given seed the result should always be the same ...

Comment: @teapot418 it must be entirely out of scratch (not the block coding language), and even if it does not shuffle much, if it can give every permutation possible in any order, its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of n-th permutation.

```
def shuffle (values, n):
    for m in range(1, len(values)):
        i = n % (m+1)
        values[m], values[i] = values[i], values[m]
        n = n // (m+1)
    return values

for i in range(24):
    print(shuffle(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], i))
```

Here is why it works. When we arrive at the `m`th iteration of the loop, the values at indexes `0, 1, ..., m-1` have already been shuffled. We then swap the `m`'th index with any one of them based on the remainder of `n / (m+1)`. And now the values at indexes `0, 1, ..., m` have been shuffled. We divide `n` by `m+1` to get rid of the information we used, and we arrive at the next loop.